# Parsing Cultural Specific Decimal and DateTime values in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, decimal

I have an ASP.NET MVC app that must work in both English and German. In one of my views, the user is inputting a decimal value and a date/time value.

```
// Get the price
string price = "1.23";
decimal priceValue = 0;
var allowedStyles = (NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint & NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
if (Decimal.TryParse(price, allowedStyles, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out priceValue))
{
  model.Price = priceValue;
}
else
  errors.Add("Please enter a valid price.");

// Parse the date
string date = "03/23/2015";
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date) == false)
{
  DateTime dateValue = DateTime.MinValue;
  if (DateTime.TryParse(saleDate, out dateValue))
  {
    model.Date = dateValue;
  }
  else
    errors.Add("Please enter a valid date.");
}
```

When the above code runs in the English culture, the `Decimal.TryParse` line returns `false`. When the code runs in the German culture, both the `Decimal.TryParse` and `DateTime.TryParse` lines return `false`. What am I doing wrong? How can I parse Decimal and DateTime values across cultures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the above code runs in the English culture, the Decimal.TryParse
>   line returns false

Because you are using bitwise AND with [`&` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) and `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint & NumberStyles.AllowThousands` generates `NumberStyles.None` which indicates no style for your element. From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx);

> Indicates that no style elements, such as leading or trailing white
>   space, thousands separators, or a decimal separator, can be present in
>   the parsed string. **The string to be parsed must consist of integral
>   decimal digits only.**

If you change `&` to `|` your `Decimal.TryParse` returns `true`.

> When the code runs in the German culture, both the Decimal.TryParse
>   and DateTime.TryParse lines return false.

Same for `Decimal.TryParse` method. **BUT**, `de-DE` culture has `,` instead of `.` as a  [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx). But it has `.` as a [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that's why it parses your `1.23` value as `123`. It thinks this is a thousands separator, not a decimal separator.

For your `DateTime.TryParse` method, since you didn't tell us what is `saleDate` exactly, looks like it is not a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), that's why it returns `false`.

If you mean `date` instead of `saleDate`, that means `MM/dd/yyyy` is not a standard date and time format for your `CurrentCulture` and neither for `de-DE` culture.

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (preferable) method with a culture that has `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) like;

```
string date = "03/23/2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    model.Date = dateValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `InvariantCulture` for that. You should parsing using 1 culture at a time, then attempting the other if that fails.